# DatabaseSessionHandler doesnt delete old sessions when I try to get logged on Laravel 9 jetstream

Tags: laravel, authentication, session, destroy, laravel-jetstream

`DatabaseSessionHandler` doesn't delete old sessions when I try to get logged on Laravel 9 jetstream. For some reason that work when I do a registration but none with the login.
This is the method what is failing;

```
    public function destroy($sessionId): bool
    {
        // DB::table('sessions')->delete($sessionId);
        $this->getQuery()->where('id', $sessionId)->delete();
    
        return true;
    }
```

I tried with DB and it works but then Ive got undefined DB with "use DB" when login out and registering. If I use `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB` it didnt work.

Its a plain laravel 9 jetstream project so must be a bug?